# Split String having `|` in R

Tags: r, regex, split, stringr

I have had an issue regarding splitting the string having `|` in R. How can I separate `abc` and `def` in this case? Thank you all for your help.

```
> str_split("abc|def", "|")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b" "c" "|" "d" "e" "f" "" 

> str_split("abc|def", ".|.")
[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex so you need to escape it. Use `str_split("abc|def", "\\|")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with base R

```
unlist(strsplit("abc|def", split = "|",fixed = TRUE))
```